# I can't install opencv in the python 3.7.4 that blender uses

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to install opencv libraries (imutils, numpy, dlib, etc). My blender version is 2.8.2 and it uses the self contain python (3.7.4). 
After updating Manjaro, there's a Python 3.8.1 also installed! and this is where all the problems begin! 
When I try to install opencv in blender' python it says that everything is already install and up to date pointing to python 3.8.1! and doesn't let me do the installation in python 3.7.4.
The problem is, when I run my scripts in blender I got an error message because some files are missing (imutils for example: `No module named 'imutils'`) and looks like the error points to the python installed within blender.

So how can I force the installation of these elements in the python within blender!?
Is there any other solution!? perhaps forcing blender to use the python in the OS?
Not sure if my hypothesis about the error is right, but at this point it is my best guest...

Please find below the console message:

```
Read prefs: /home/manjaro/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /home/manjaro/Descargas/blender-2.82-e0cd5b980fc5-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.82/python
Read blend: /home/manjaro/Descargas/blender-2.82-e0cd5b980fc5-linux-glibc217-x86_64/carpeta trabajo blender 2.82/vincent_modify/Vincent to be modify6b83.blend
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[3]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[3]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[3]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manjaro/Descargas/blender-2.82-e0cd5b980fc5-linux-glibc217-x86_64/carpeta trabajo blender 2.82/vincent_modify/Vincent to be modify6b83.blend/OpenCVAnimOperator", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Manjaro 18.1.4

Blender 2.82

Python 3.7.4 (in blender) and 3.8.1 (in the OS)

Thanks!

Comment: Blender has it's own API so you can't change it's version of python sadly.

Comment: Yohello 1 I know, but there should be a way to downgrade os python to match the one in blender, or a way to install what I need in blender' python...Maybe I can set PYTHONPATH to to an external Python (the same version that uses blender though)...I don't know, that's why I'm asking! but there should be a solution...

Comment: How exactly did you try to install the package in Blender?

Comment: @Robert Gützkow

```python3 -m ensurepip
```


```python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --user

```

```python3 -m pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python imutils numpy dlib --user

```



The problem is everytime I tried I got a message saying that everything is installed and up to date pointing to python in the OS

Comment: Well you need to issue the commands for Blender's Python, since python3 is the alias for the python 3.8.1 installed on your system (and not for Blender's Python). Navigate to the directory where you've installed Blender and open `./2.82/python/bin`. Run the commands using `./python -m pip install [...]`

Comment: @Robert Gützkow

that's what I did (I should have been more specific). The problem is that once I navigate to ./2.82/python/bin, I can't use ./python because it doesn't exist. My only chance is using ./python3.7m.

So now I did:
./python3.7m -m ensurepip  
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3 setuptools-40.8.0

./python3.7m -m pip install --upgrade pip --user 
Successfully installed pip-19.3.1
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I don't understand this...

Comment: @Robert Gützkow

./python3.7m -m pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python imutils numpy dlib --user
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python, opencv-contrib-python, imutils, dlib
    Running setup.py install for imutils ... done
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
and got a huge error

Comment: @Robert Gützkow

not sure where to go from there. It looks like it doesn't matter what I do I'll end up having pretty much the same errors. I could try and install cmake and try to install again dlib. The last time I tried to do that I did:
pip install cmake
Successfully installed cmake-3.15.3

Comment: and then I did:
./python3.7m -m pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python imutils numpy dlib --user
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /home/manjaro/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.1.2.30)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in /home/manjaro/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.1.2.30)
Requirement already satisfied: imutils in /home/manjaro/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/manjaro/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.18.0)

Comment: Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/92/05c3b98636661cb80d190a5a777dd94effcc14c0f6893222e5ca81e74fbc/dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error

and got again the very same error

Comment: Looks like only dlib failed to install (not sure why without seeing the error message). BTW you don't need ensurepip, Blender ships with pip already installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102665/discussion-between-peat-and-robert-gutzkow).